# IS Json_encode() more secure than serialize in PHP?

Tags: php, security, exploit

I was testing the exploit of a website.

The vulnerability is about PHP object injection.

The misuse of `unserialize()` may cause these problems.

Also, I found a warning in the official php manual as below:

[image: warning]

They suggest that we should use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`.

However, I am wondering why `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` are more secure than `serialize()` and `unsrialize()`?

Comment: `json_decode` doesn't decode to specific classes (only stdClass), `unserialize` does.

Comment: there is no "security" differences between any of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that serialize stores an object. If you change the contents of the string before unserialize you can trick the system to run malicious code.

With json_* functions you do not store the object, just the data. Upon "unpacking" the object has to be instantiated from original sources, and only then can be given json_decoded data to process.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It is helpful ~~